# Jhipster : can't build a prod profile war : gulp test fails

Tags: maven, gulp, jhipster

when I try to build a prod profile war, with mvn -Pprod package, I am getting this gulp error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation') in /home/myapp/dev/workspace/applicationRh/src/test/javascript/spec/app/services/auth/auth.services.spec.js (line 9)
/home/myapp/dev/workspace/applicationRh/src/test/javascript/spec/app/services/auth/auth.services.spec.js:9:1596
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 64 of 64 (64 FAILED) (0 secs / 1.231 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 64 of 64 (64 FAILED) ERROR (2.671 secs / 1.231 secs)
[22:28:40] 'test' errored after 9.84 s
[22:28:40] Error: 1
at formatError (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
```

Does anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't package your app in production if it has test failures. Run `grunt test` to see which test fail, and correct that test.
Of course, if you don't want to be bothered with tests, just delete them :-)

Comment: One of my trainees had injected some bad dependency in app.module.js.... that caused the tests fail...:) Thank you.